# How to use Azure EventHub ProxyOptions

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

In azure-java-sdk samples there is an example - PublishEventsWithWebSocketsAndProxy.java

```
// By default, the AMQP port 5671 is used, but clients can use web sockets, port 443.
        // When using web sockets, developers can specify proxy options.
        // ProxyOptions.SYSTEM_DEFAULTS can be used if developers want to use the JVM configured proxy.
        ProxyOptions proxyOptions = new ProxyOptions(ProxyAuthenticationType.DIGEST,
            new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("10.13.1.3", 9992)),
            "digest-user", "digest-user-password");

        // Instantiate a client that will be used to call the service.
        EventHubProducerClient producer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
            .transportType(AmqpTransportType.AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS)
            .proxyOptions(proxyOptions)
            .connectionString(connectionString)
            .buildProducerClient();
```

But I don't understand the paramter values -  10.13.1.3 , digest-user , digest-user-password

can anyone tell me, if this is what I have to use, if the organization has Web App Firewall, connecting to Azure

Answer (score 0):

The parameters that you're referring to are configuring access to a proxy server.  In this case, `10.13.1.3` is the address of the proxy server to use, `digest-user` is the username for authentication, while `digest-user-password` is its password.  This set of credentials is used because the options are using `ProxyAuthenticationType.DIGEST` for the example.

With respect to your scenario, how you need to configure the client to use your organization's proxy isn't something that can be answered generally.  It will depend heavily on how your organization configures the environment, manage network flow, and apply security practices.

I'd recommend reaching out to an IT Ops representative in your organization for that information; once you have that, we can help with any questions or problems that you run into configuring the client to work within that context.